# Increasing the default size of instances of java.util.Stack

Tags: java, stack

The `Stack` library creates an object of a class that extends from `Vector` which in turn implements a `List`.

I am adding a finite number of non primitive objects to the Stack (around 20) and seeing stack overflow errors. Since the `Stack` library extends from `Vector` I am assuming that the default capacity is 10.

How can I increase the capacity of the Stack?

I tried using setSize(int newSize) but as per the docs:

> If the new size is greater than the current size, new null items are
>   added to the end of the vector. If the new size is less than the
>   current size, all components at index newSize and greater are
>   discarded.

Which means if I set the size more than 10, all new elements after the 10th index become null. Which is basically useless.

Is there any other way to increase the capacity of the stack?

My code:

```
private void sendTransporterToHuman(Coord dest) {
        successfuljourney = sendTransporterTo(dest, HUMAN);
        if(!successfuljourney) {
            this.destinations.add(dest); //this.destinations is the stack
            sendTransporterToHuman(new Coord(dest.X() - 1, dest.Y()));
        } else {
            if(this.destinations.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            } else {
                sendTransporterToHuman(this.destinations.pop());
            }
        }
    }
```

Context for the same - a destination may fail if there is another transporter there already. so this new destination is actually the destination right behind that transporter. That way multiple transporters make a queue for the destination. This code does just that and the number of recursive calls will be at max the number or transporters in the queue line - which I know is finite (around 20). So I am assured I do not get stuck with infinite recursion either.

Comment: Show us your code.  Stack overlow errors usually mean you have a recursive call with no proper exit clause.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you show an [mcve]?

Comment: Stack overflow errors have to do with the function call stack that Java uses to keep track of function calls. It has **nothing** to do with the size of the `Stack` data structure.

Comment: They will be initialized with NULL. you can always add values over those places. Size is already increased.

Comment: @Ryan Have added my code.

Comment: If you have a lot of entries then your method is going to keep calling itself.  The better approach is to have a while loop outside of the method to keep calling while destination isn't empty.

Comment: @Ryan - as I mentioned, I know that the number of entries is not going to be more than 20. If the number of entries were going to be significantly high then I would not have chosen a recursive approach in the first place.

Comment: You may start with 20, but if you have a failure, you're adding it back to stack and then calling the function with a new Coord, which might get added to the stack.  Your recursion is very bad.

Comment: @Ryan Tthe aim is to go to a destination say 'dest'. If dest journey is unsuccessful then try for a new destination before trying for 'dest'. The aim for my recursive method is to keep trying for new destinations until there is a success and then try the old failed once.

Context for the same - a destination may fail if there is another transporter there already. so this new destination is actually the destination right behind that transporter. That way multiple transporters make a queue for the destination. This code does just that. can you share a better way to implement the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so instead of finding ways to change the capacity of the `java.util.Stack` class, what I have done is implemented my own Stack class for the Class Coord:

```
package utilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import simulator.Coord;
public class CoordStack {

    private ArrayList<Coord> coords;
    private int lastIndex;

    public CoordStack(int capacity) {
        this.coords = new ArrayList<Coord>(capacity);
    }

    public void push(Coord c) {
        this.coords.add(c);
    }

    public Coord pop() {
        this.lastIndex = this.coords.size() - 1;
        return this.coords.remove(lastIndex);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.coords.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A better approach is

```
private void processDestinations() {
    while(!destinations.isEmpty()) {
         sendTransporterToHuman(destinations.pop());
    }
}

private void sendTransporterToHuman(Coord dest) {
    successfuljourney = sendTransporterTo(dest, HUMAN);
    if(!successfuljourney) {
        this.destinations.add(dest); //this.destinations is the stack
    }
}
```

Comment: But where do I call the ```processDestinations```? I always start with an empty stack when I call ```sendTransporterToHuman```.